# Get real time HTC Vive controller position in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a game and one of the things I need is a selection reticule that drags on the Terrain on the floor. I have a function dropVecToFloor that takes in a Vector and changes the y to the terrain y at that spot. However, when I poll the controller using SteamVR_Controller.Input(index).transform.pos, it gives me a location a quarter of a second late. How could I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide some code? Especially at what point those two methods are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If I use a SteamVR_TrackedObject, I don't get the lag that I get with SteamVR_Controller.Input(index). I don't understand the difference, but it SteamVR_Controller gives me lag.

Comment: Yes, It worked just getting the position like this:       
                             
    void Start () {
        trackedObject = GetComponent<SteamVR_TrackedObject>();
    }
void Update () {
        Vector3 pos = trackedObject.transform.position;
    }